# Error while extracting public key from PKCS11 and Asn1crypto signed certificate

Tags: python, ssl, pkcs#11, asn.1, asn1crypto

In addition to this thread: [Where is the trust chain? [python] asn1crypto and pkcs11 Aladdin USB eToken](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50416132/where-is-the-trust-chain-python-asn1crypto-and-pkcs11-aladdin-usb-etoken)

I tried:

```
openssl x509 -pubkey -noout -in cert.pem 
Error getting public key
140003854860736:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_check_tlen:wrong tag:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:1129:
140003854860736:error:0D06C03A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_d2i_ex_primitive:nested asn1 error:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:693:
140003854860736:error:0D08303A:asn1 encoding routines:asn1_template_noexp_d2i:nested asn1 error:../crypto/asn1/tasn_dec.c:626:Field=n, Type=RSA
140003854860736:error:0408B004:rsa routines:rsa_pub_decode:RSA lib:../crypto/rsa/rsa_ameth.c:51:
140003854860736:error:0B09407D:x509 certificate routines:x509_pubkey_decode:public key decode error:../crypto/x509/x_pubkey.c:124:
```

The contents of this file is:

```
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
```

What's wrong with this file or with the code from that thread? I can't extract the public key.

Comment: Certificate is signed public key

Comment: Hello. Sorry, I did not understand. Afaik, a certificate is composed by some elements, which includes the public key, signature algorithm and the the signature itself. So, anyone could verify this signature using these information. So, the public key must be extractable. Don't you agree?

Comment: Please check this Q/A: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17155710/2908599

Comment: Hi, I already did that in this Q/A link. Did you try that commands with this certificate I pasted here?